# Can we calculate moments (mean, var, skewness, kurtosis) of a signal in frequency domain?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, statistics

The computation of the `mean`, `variance`, [skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) and [kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) of a time series in the time domain is straightforward from their definition formulae.

I need these statistic values in different frequency bands. Currently I apply different bandpass filters to the signal and repeat to compute the statistics. I'm curious if it is possible to compute them from the spectrum in the frequency domain?

Comment: Well I know off hand that the first two can be calculated, but I am not personally certain without researching regarding the last two. The mean is the DC component of the signal in the frequency domain, and the variance of the signal in the frequency domain is equal to the variance of the signal in the time domain (as given by Parseval's theorem).

Comment: The DC value at `f = 0 Hz` is one single value, only for the full signal. Seems it's impossible to get the mean values of different frequencies from the spectrum.

Comment: You get the mean value of the time domain signal from the value of $f=0$ Hz, which is indeed part of the spectrum.  So consistent with your question, it is absolutely possible to compute the mean if you have the complete frequency domain spectrum, as the complete spectrum always includes the DC value.

Comment: But I see your new edit now. What does the mean value in a different frequency band signify to you? The average of what? The average power over that band of frequencies? Or something else? You should probably update your question to be more specific as to what units you want these statistics for in any given band.

Comment: Note that each frequency (bin in a discrete Fourier Transform for example to consider discrete samples) is a random variable which has all the statistics you describe. Maybe some more info on our high level purpose and what you are trying to achieve and why may help get a better answer.  When you apply different bandpass filters, if I follow correctly you will get a mean of zero for every case except when the filter includes DC---is that accurate to what you are doing?

Comment: Oh, correct for the DC. The mean value is zero for all bandpassed signals.

Comment: I'm treating realtime signals and for every several minutes computing the average power, skewness and kurtosis in different frequency bands.

Comment: Then yes, at least for variance (power) the power in the frequency bands of interest is equal to the power in the time domain signal if you passed that signal through a filter and then used your time domain approach to computing variance (given Parseval's theorem).

Comment: As for Kurtosis and Skewness I would think you should be able to compute it given the process of filtering and applying the time domain formula together represents mathematical computation on the original samples alone (therefore the information is there!). I just can't see how to get there so will be interested to see the best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your time series $x(t)=s(t)+n(t)$ where $s(t)$ is a deterministic signal,and $n(t)$ is independent Gaussian noise,  it has a pdf of the form
$$
p(x(t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x(t) - s(t)}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)
$$
the first moment is
$$
E\left\{ x(t) \right\} = s(t) 
$$
which is NOT the DC component of the Fourier Transform of a sample. The first moment is not a constant and the time series is not WSS, and the first moment is not equal to the time average.

Comment: well, this is a response to the comments, not an answer to the Q

Comment: How it not an answer to the question?